# How to lock root privileged VS code to Ubuntu Launcher?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCODE for obvious purpose and I am running it via root permissions on Ubuntu using a command
`sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"`

**Problem-**
My Ubuntu Launcher has a VSCODE icon but that VSCODE is not a root user and each time I want to run it as a root user, I have to run the above command.

How can I fix the VSCODE with root privileges in my Ubuntu Launcher for quick access?